# Using UIWebView as a script engine

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a survey engine for the iPhone.  We use a declarative xml format that can be downloaded post store install.  It's working pretty well but not being able to script is becoming problematic.  I have this idea to use a webView to execute javascript code to provide this functionality.

My question is will this run afoul of Apple's rule of not downloading executable script code?  They do seem to allow for downloading of JS code that will run in a web view.  Would they consider this approach an abuse of this rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. A lot of native applications are actually built this way. They simply open a webview and load a web page, with all the logic done in javascript.

Comment: This scenario is a bit different.  all the rendering will be done in native code.  im just using javascript to do non visual logic like visibility calculations or string calculations i then marshal between the native app and the web view.  I'm pretty sure I wont be breaking any rules here though.